# Allow user to resize widgets at runtime in QT5

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

I have an application written in C++/QT5 with a QListView widget within a QHBoxLayout within a QGroupBox. There is also a QTabWidget in the main window. I would like the user to be able to resize the QListView widget by clicking and dragging and for the other items to automatically resize themselves accordingly.

I feel like this should be something that is easily done within the framework of QT5, but I can't for the life of me find a way. Even having a border on the list view that I can resize within the code of my application would be a start.

Comment: Do you know [`QSplitter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html)?

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea what to look for. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jhnnslschnr I was able to solve this via the QSplitter widget. If you're using QtCreator as I was, you can use QSplitter simply by Ctrl-clicking the widgets you want in the splitter and then selecting "Lay out horizontally (vertically) in splitter". The user can now select the partitioning at run-time.